# Disable DropBox's PDF reader

Tags: dropbox

I have been seeing recently that DropBox opens PDF files stored in it through its own reader. I would like to open all my PDF files through Adobe, no matter where their location is. I do not want to use this extra functionality provided by DropBox.

How can I disable this option in DropBox? I could not find any option to disable PDF viewing. Is it a feature that must be added in future by DropBox?

Comment: Yes, this is a pain. Despite selecting "More" > "Open With" and picking Adobe Reader "Always" (which is then set as a default app within Dropbox itself - managed through Dropbox settings) it still opens Dropbox's internal PDF viewer when simply tapping the PDF file inside Dropbox. You must still select "More" > "Open With" each time, only now you don't need to pick "Adobe Reader" from the list (if you have more than 1 PDF viewer app installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dropbox, next to your `file.pdf` there is an arrow button (on the right), click on it and a menu will appear with options :

- `Share`, `Add to favorites`, `Delete` and `More`.

Click on `More` and then it will display the options :

- `Rename`, `Move`, `Open with` and `Export`.

Click on `Open with` and just select the application you want your `file.pdf` to open with.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the built-in PDF support can be disabled. I would suggest exporting and downloading the file instead, so that you can open it with and PDF reader of your choice.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly "Export" the PDF, you can "Open With" instead. From the drop down menu next to the file, select "More", then "Open With" and pick "Adobe Reader".

Answer (score 1):

Open in the previewer in dropbox then click the screen to reveal the bottom menu, click the 3 dots in the bottom right and select open with.....  then select your choice app.

Comment: The "3 dot menu" in the PDF viewer (which I assume you are referring to by "previewer") does not contain the option "open with...", just "Export" and "Delete".

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Adobe Reader app.
2. Add your Dropbox account in the Adobe Reader app.
3. Open your Dropbox folders and files from the Adobe Reader app.